# Has there ever been 3 goals in the same match with the same scorer and assister?

Tags: football

Has there ever been 3 (or more) goals in the same match with not only had the same scorer for each, but where all assisted by the same player?

In other-words a hat-trick for both goals and assists.

I'm only counting fully professional matches OR internationals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

In a Premier League match between Tottenham Hotspur and Southampton, in September 2020, Son Heung-Min scored four goals for Tottenham, with Harry Kane assisting all four. You can find the match report [here](https://www.premierleague.com/match/58914).